# CompanyMask - GroupMask to sharing data between companies ACUMATICA

Tags: acumatica, shared-data

I'm researching for sharing data from Parent Company to another child company and has read 2 blog below but I don't know that how It's work and how can I implement it.

This is the link of blog:

> [Company Mask](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/08/restriction-groups-architecture.html)
>
> [Group Mask](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/10/company-mask-for-data-sharing-between-tenats-in-acumatica.html)

What I'm expecting is share data about Inventory or User or anything else to another company because I just want to use 1 product for all company.

Is there any ideas to use Company mask and Group mask to share data to another company?

Thanks for reading and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing data between tenants (companies), CompanyMask is the field.  GroupMask is for restriction groups and is to do with row level permission within a tenant.  There is an old but very effective blog post here: https://blog.acumatica.com.sg/2013/05/understanding-company-setup-options.html that talks about it in great detail that should get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will see that blog and respond as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi @Nayan Mansinha.
Do you know how to insert 1 record to any table that we had set Status is Shared with the others company?.
I'm stuck when insert record to db by my project. Its just create 1 record in company I had login, not insert to the others company.